# Android: Virtual Keyboard: the use has no idea what EditText he is filling in

Tags: android, layout, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a few forms that the user has to fill in and I use EditText to enter the information.

the problem is, when the user uses the virtual keyboard there no information about which field he is filling in.

so its fine when there is only one field but when he has 4 or more he fills in the first one, presses next and he has to remember what was the second field and so on

is there a way to set a title in the EditText so that instead of being just a text zone it has a title to remind the user what he is inputing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a hint, which pre-fills the `EditText` with a useful reminder (in a faded-out colour). This disappears when the user starts typing.

```
android:hint="Type your name here"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the input method editor bits don't let you do that (though that would be nice). Try setting the attribute `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` on the EditText instances.